# Android OpenGL 1.1 FBO and VBO support

Tags: android, opengl-es, vbo, fbo

Is there a way of achieving any one of the following 2 goals while using GL1.1 on Android's Java VM:
1. Render to texture using FBO
2. Use VBO to pass vertex information to GPU memory

I have a small application that renders several thousands of textures to the screen, using vertex arrays and there is a severe performance problem. However the frame doesn't change often and can be cached either in a texture or just ready in GPU memory.

I have found no working examples or good tutorials on how to achieve this with the old version of OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used FBOs on Android with OpenGL ES 2.0 extensively and with 1.1 on Linux.  For 1.1 you need the FBO extensions or use pbuffers.  If the OpenGL ES 1.1 drivers you have on your Android device reports having the FBO extensions, they should work. Most of them do because some of the Android SDK OpenGL ES demos require the FBO extensions.  This article has example code of using FBOs on 1.1 on Linux:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES

I think there are also examples in the Android SDK that use VBOs on 1.1 too, such as the "Hello Effects" demo.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

Comment: I got FBO's working by using it as extension. However, I do not seem to have any tutorial or example to use VBO's with Java, and although they might be supported by the GL version the Java interface to android might not provide the necessary functions to do it. (I have seen examples with the NDK though).

Comment: The examples in the SDK that use VBOs with OpenGL ES 1.1 are actually CubeMapActivity and MatrixPaletteRenderer, which are part of the API Demos in the Graphics section.